# Sub line bundle of a vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

I am trying to read Friedman's "Algebraic surfaces and holomorphic vector bundles". I am unable to follow a claim (on pg 32) that any globally generated rank 2 vector bundle (say) $E$ on a complex algebraic surface $X$ has $\mathcal{O}_X$ as a sub bundle.

My doubt is this that if $s \in Hom(\mathcal{O}_X, E)$ be a global section, then will the map $\mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow E$ be an injection on the vanishing locus of $s$?

Comment: Note that Friedman defined a sub line bundle to be a rank one subsheaf which is itself a line bundle. This is a weaker assumption than requiring the cokernel to be locally free (or equivalently, each fiber of $E$ contains a rank one vector space). Of course in the stronger version, a sub line bundle corresponds to a non-vanishing section, but in Friedman’s sense, a nonzero section is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $s\ne 0$, then the map $\mathcal O_X\to E$ induced by $s$ is injective.

Indeed, suppose for some non-empty open subset $U$ of $X$, the map 
$$O_X(U)\to E(U), \quad f\mapsto fs|_U $$
is not injective. Then there exists $f\in O_X(U)$ non-zero such that $fs|_U=0$. 
As $E$ is locally free, this implies that $s|_U=0$. But again because $E$ is locally free and $X$ is integral, the restriction map $E(X)\to E(U)$ is injective, so $s|_U\ne 0$. Contradiction.

I think you make confusion between the vanishing locus of $s$  and its zero divisor.

Comment: Thanks! This clarifies it.